# Does casting a pointer to "void*" have any effect when placement new is called?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, new-operator, copy-constructor, placement-new

I'm reviewing code of a custom container and some portions of it create elements like this:

```
::new( (void*)&buffer[index] ) CStoredType( other );
```

and some do like this:

```
::new( &buffer[index] ) CStoredType( other );
```

So both use placement new to invoke a copy constructor to create an element by copying some other element, but in one case a pointer to the new element storage is passed as is and in another it is casted to `void*`.

Does this cast to `void*` have any effect?

Comment: The Right Way is probably [`std::addressof(buffer[index])`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you could overload operator new for a nonvoid pointer. The cast ensures that the void pointer overload is taken.

For example

```
void* operator new(size_t s, env * e);
```

Comment: I guess that's what I get for writing an example *before* posting. :P

Comment: Good point.  That possibility hadn't occurred to me.  (The probability of having an overload for the same type of pointer seems fairly small, but better safe than sorry.)

Comment: I thought you were going to say something about overloaded `&`-operators and `void*`-conversion operators! Imagine the possibilities...

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Casting to `void*` won't help against overloaded `&`.

Comment: @sharptooth: I was thinking of something more roundabout. The type of `buffer[i]` could overload `operator&`, and the return type of that operator could define a conversion operator to `void*`. That way you could produce very sinister effects perhaps...

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Yes, very sinister indeed, but this again has nothing to do with casting to `void*` - the problem is there because `&` is used to get address of object in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

A compilable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

void* operator new(std::size_t, int* x)
{
    std::cout << "a side effect!" << std::endl;

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int buffer[1];

    new ((void*)&buffer[0]) char;
    new (&buffer[0]) char;
}
```